# Mac - keeping an application always in the foreground - how?

Tags: macos, utilities

On my Mac running Snow Leopard, I want one of my application window to always be in the foreground (on top of all others) -

searching brings the 'afloat' external application : http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/

I am wondering if there is any native way to achieve it? If not, any experience with afloat? I am wary of installing external apps for fear of risking quality, performance and stability of my Mac

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you try: myWindow.level = NSScreenSaverWindowLevel

This should keep it on top of other windows in all applications.

Comment: thanks for your response - I do not code this application or have any control on it - I launch this app and then it launches another window (a child window) and thats the window i want to stay in the foreground